# Mysql trigger doing calculations in 2 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, triggers

Im trying to make a trigger that has to do a subtraction if order_status changes from 0 to 1 or 2. The value of quantity in the updated order_status row should be subtracted from quantity_in_stock in another table. This is what ive tried, but its not working for me.

```
begin
   DECLARE orderQuantity INT(11);
   if old.order_status = 0 and new.order_status != 0 then 
   select quantity into orderQuantity from `order` where id=new.id;
   update product_in_stock
   set quantity_in_stock = sum(quantity_in_stock - orderQuantity)
   where id=1;
   end if;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have defined your own `sum` function, the way you are using is wrong

instead of `set quantity_in_stock = sum(quantity_in_stock - orderQuantity)`

it should be `set quantity_in_stock = sum(quantity_in_stock) - sum(orderQuantity)`

But again, you can't use aggregate function directly like this unless it's in `having` clause.

What you can do, `declare two variable -> fetch the sum separately and store them to variable -> use them` like

```
DECLARE sum_quantity_in_stock INT(11);
DECLARE sum_orderQuantity INT(11);

select sum(quantity_in_stock) into sum_quantity_in_stock from sometable;
select sum(orderQuantity) into sum_orderQuantity from sometable;


set quantity_in_stock = sum_quantity_in_stock - sum_orderQuantity
```

Comment: I need to add table and stuff to the last line, right?

Comment: @MacLuc, Add the code I have mentioned last and then use the variables in subtraction.